# Understanding of $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {1} {n+1}=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Proof. Let $\varepsilon>0$. We need to find $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac {1} {n+1} < \varepsilon$ for any $n\geq N$. By the Archimedean property, there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ which is greater then $\dfrac {1} {\varepsilon }-1$. So, as $N>\dfrac {1} {\varepsilon }-1$, we have $\dfrac {1} {N+1}<\varepsilon$.For $n\geq N$, we have $\dfrac {1} {n+1} \leq \dfrac {1} {N+1} < \varepsilon$.

My question is: For $n\geq N$, how we have $\dfrac {1} {n+1} \leq \dfrac {1} {N+1}$ ?

Comment: One part out of a million is much smaller than one part out of ten.

Comment: Title looks deliberate

Comment: The proof says that ''We need to find $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$...'' My question is that what did we find $N$ in the proof?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{N+1} \iff N+1 \leq n+1 \iff n \geq N$$

Comment: I know this. But, $\dfrac {1} {n+1}$ and $\dfrac {1} {N+1} $ are sequences. Yet, $N+1$ and $n+1$ are index of sequence.

Comment: They aren't sequences. The expression written is just a number. The sequence notation is: $$\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$

Comment: Okey. Then, I have questions. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We need to find $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$. i.e. we need to find index of sequence $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$,right?  ...such that $\dfrac {1} {n+1} < \varepsilon$. i.e., $\left( \dfrac {1} {n+1}\right) _{n}\mathbb{N} < \varepsilon$, it is sequence,right?  ...for any $n\geq N$ it is index of sequence, right?

Comment: You need to find $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have: $$\frac{1}{n+1}<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by a *larger* number gives a *smaller* result (I'm assuming positive numbers here). For example, $7>6$ but
$$ \frac17 < \frac16 .$$
So if $n \geq N$, then also $n+1\geq N+1$. This means
$$ \frac1{n+1} \leq \frac1{N+1} .$$